getEnvelopeDocGenFormFields returns 200 with no form fields in docusign api but the document has the sender fields
Issue to access sender fields from the docusign api
Here are the steps that i followed:
First, I have created brand new docx file and added the {{placeholder}} which is sender fields per the article here manually.I folllowed below article how to create sender fields
Sample sequence with manually created sender field syntax. reference: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/documents/document-generation/

I did step 1 to 4 manually (steps from above link)

creating document with the sender fields, 

added document to the template in the docusing portal.

I have created the envelop in the status created.

**Issue is **: when i call the  getEnvelopeDocGenFormFields API with the correct template id and document id (1), i get no form fields.I did verify for sure i am calling the correct template and document id. you can verify in the attachment with the placeholders.


Yes I created document in the .docx format added place holders/sender fields in the format {{XXXX}} and uploaded to the portal (my account is personal developer account)
Can you please let me know where am i missing?


Does the document inside the template show "DOCUMENT GENERATION" when you open the template you created on the web app and look at it (edit template) and see the document

You wrote this:

**Issue is **: when i call the getEnvelopeDocGenFormFields API with the correct template id and document id (1), i get no form fields.I
did verify for sure i am calling the correct template and document id.
you can verify in the attachment with the placeholders.

Now if this is indeed what you did, you didn't do it correctly. because getEnvelopeDocGenFormFields should be called with an envelopeID not a templateID. You make this call after you already have an envelope crated from the template. At this point in the process - the template is no longer being used, and it's all about the envelope.
